# Alcatraz - Xcode Command Line Tools are not currently installed

Tags: xcode, git, macos, command-line-tool, alcatraz

I'm managing Xcode plug-ins via Alcatraz.

Everything was alright until I installed and then uninstalled Git following instruction in the uninstalled.sh file in official [git.zip](https://git-scm.com/download/mac) file:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/git/   (in my case it's /usr/local/git/bin/git)
sudo rm /etc/paths.d/git   
sudo rm /etc/manpaths.d/git
```

I have no idea what I've done with git would affect Alcatraz.

Once I click Package Manager in Xcode I get this error:

[image]

I found nothing to download in the Preference Download section, 
and I did  try to install the Command Line Tool following [Xcode Command Line Tool tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html)

Here's how I verified it:

```
myMacBook-Air:~ me$ xcode-select -p 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

And even:

```
myMacBook-Air:~ me$ gcc --version    
Configured with:--prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1   
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0   
Thread model: posix
```

The warning still pops up.

Did I fail to install the command line tool?

(or maybe it's not about the git but has something related to the Xcode 7 upgrade?)

How could I fix this?

Comment: What does `which git` show?

Comment: @trojanfoe it showed `/usr/local/git/bin/git`

Comment: But you stated that you deleted `/usr/local/git`.

Comment: @trojanfoe yep that's the official command and I did modify it to my path, noted it.

Comment: Well that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @trojanfoe then this may not be related to the git uninstallation?

Comment: No I think it's `git` related.  But if you deleted `/usr/local/git` then `which git` would not show it, so it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @trojanfoe aww I just installed it back... cause I thought that might help (but not). Sorry for taking you so long =/. The `which git` showed nothing when git was uninstalled actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206715/alcatraz-xcode-command-line-tools-are-not-currently-installed/206767#206767) actually works,

looks like Alcatraz has something to do with git.